# How to run jest tests that import a fixture?

Tags: jestjs

I'm importing a fixture into a few test files.

The fixture looks like this:

```js
export default makeFakeBoopServiceData = (arg1, arg2, arg3) => {
  // some complex way of making fake data.
  return fakeBoopData;
}
```

In my example this is emulating what our backend services are doing (called in our non-test code by an endpoint for the `boopService`), and I want to use this fixture so I can use realistic data in the test.

But not all of my tests use this fixture, not even all the tests that test code that uses the `boopService` need this fixture (some tests are simple enough they don't need that full set up).

I'd like to `--findRelatedTests` to find tests related to/importing from  `test/fixture/boopServiceData.fixture.ts` where I have defined `makeFakeBoopServiceData` but when I run:

```js
npm run jest -- --findRelatedTests test/fixture/boopServiceData.fixture.ts
```

I get an error saying "No tests found, exiting with code 1".

I can just recursively grep for the import statement then transform into a list of tests to run, but I thought that what the CLI command was for (and more complicated scenarios that don't involve direct importing)?

Am I using `findRelatedTests` wrong? Is there a more correct CLI command?

Comment: Try adding file paths to **source** files that rely on the mock while under test.

Comment: @morganney that's a different situation though. I'm mocking data for a server call, and not all tests that use the equivalent data use the fixture.

Comment: You're using the CLI option incorrectly though when you reference something other than a source file. Good luck I guess.

Comment: @morganney I thought that might be the case, which is why I ended my question with: "Am I using it wrong? Is there a more correct cli command?" Do you know of a cli command that does what I want, if one does not exist, well then that's a valid answer.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you are trying to do, but if you want to run tests for only certain specs then there is [testmatch](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--testmatch-glob1--globn) which accepts globs.

Comment: @morganney any clearer with my edit?

Comment: @morganney sorry to pester you, is this clearer since my edit?

Comment: As I've already mentioned, yes, you are using `findRelatedTests` wrong because you are passing the location of **test** files instead of **source** files. If you want to run tests for only the specs that include the mock, then set up some naming convention so you can use `testMatch` or `testPathPattern` or `testNamePattern`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `findRelatedTests` wrong by passing in the location of **test** files instead of **source** files.

You asked about another CLI option, and there are three others that could help in combination with some naming convention you create:

- [`--testMatch`](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--testmatch-glob1--globn)
- [`--testPathPattern`](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--testpathpatternregex)
- [`--testNamePattern`](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--testnamepatternregex)

Here is an example using `--testNamePattern` and the convention that your tests use a name with the string `fakeBoopServiceData`:

**test.ts**

```js
describe('some module', () => {
  test('it works with fakeBoopServiceData', () => {
    // your test...
  })
})
```

**cli**

```
npm run jest -- --testNamePattern=fakeBoopServiceData
```

The other CLI options mentioned apply to *filenames* not test names.